How to Determine Printer Margins in Delphi
I'm in the process of developing an application that could be run on any number of possible printers. I located the GetDeviceCaps function and it has most of the elements necessary to compute accurate size page margins; however, when I run the following code the results stored are zero, except that the printer name was correct.
type
    PDeviceInfo = record
        hPrinter: THandle;
        PrintName: string;
        PrintWidth: integer;
        PrintHeight: integer;
        PrintPhysWidth: integer;
        PrintPhysHeight: integer;
        PrintPhysOfsX: integer;
        PrintPhysOfsY: integer;
        PrintScaleX: integer;
        PrintScaleY: integer;
    end;

procedure TForm1.GetPrinterCaps;
var
    PName: string;
begin
    with Printer do
    begin
        PDInfo.PrintName:=Printers[PrinterIndex];
        OpenPrinter(PChar(PDInfo.PrintName),PDInfo.hPrinter,nil);
        PDInfo.PrintWidth:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,HORZRES);
        PDInfo.PrintHeight:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,VERTRES);
        PDInfo.PrintPhysWidth:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,PHYSICALWIDTH);
        PDInfo.PrintPhysHeight:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,PHYSICALHEIGHT);
        PDInfo.PrintPhysOfsX:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,PHYSICALOFFSETX);
        PDInfo.PrintPhysOfsY:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,PHYSICALOFFSETY);
        PDInfo.PrintScaleX:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,SCALINGFACTORX);
        PDInfo.PrintScaleY:=GetDeviceCaps(PDInfo.hPrinter,SCALINGFACTORY);
        ClosePrinter(PDInfo.hPrinter);
    end;
end;

The problem is that even if the code above provided the results I was looking for, it doesn't provide the size of the non-printable area on all four sides of the page. The following image  shows what I'm referring to. The gray area is the non-printable area of the printer using a standard 8.5 x 11" piece of paper. The black line is the printable area and the red lines are the 1" margin on all four side, that I manually computed by actually measuring the distance of the gray area. The results was the top, bottom and left side areas were all 1/8" (or 75 pixels), but the right side was 3/16" (or 113 pixels). Also, I made the assumption that the printer was running in 600 DPI. An 8.5 x 11" piece of paper assuming 600 DPI is 5100 x 6600 pixels from left to right and top to bottom. The printable area is 4900 x 6400 pixels. We cannot assume that the non-printable area is 100 pixels, as I already shown, its not accurate.

When I was digging around the Winapi.Windows unit for the DeviceCapabilities function I noticed that it was commented out for some reason, and not accessible or callable? There wasn't any other functions listed with similar names either.
{function DeviceCapabilitiesEx; external gdi32 name 'DeviceCapabilities';}

I have looked at several articles and questions about printing, but none of them directly provides the solution or points me in the right direction:
GetDeviceCaps Function from MS
DeviceCapablitiesA Function from MS
Device Capabilities
Paper Size Names
UPDATE: I was able to get the GetDeviceCaps functions in the code above to operate properly. As suspected the non-printable as defined under PHYSICALOFFSETX and PHYSICALOFFSETY are 100 each.
My questions:

How can the non-printable area and the current DPI, along with other potentially necessary device settings be obtained from Windows or the printer driver?

What is the proper way to obtain the printer information I attempted to get via the GetDeviceCaps function, or other device related functions?


